# Change 'Administration theme' not working - still shows current theme for administrative tasks

Tags: 7, theming

I have a custom theme that works fine. I want to use D7's 'Seven' theme for administration. However, despite it being chosen already, Drupal uses my custom theme for administration and editing.

If I change themes to a Drupal default theme like Bartik, then, I can change the administration theme to whatever I want, even my custom theme, and everything works as expected.

This tells me I have something wrong with my theme.  What am I missing? Are there any default drupal theme variables that I need to include to make sure that the overlay theme is indeed Seven (or whatever I choose).  What could be causing my theme to disregard my Administration Theme choice and use my custom theme regardless of the setting?

note: I am trying to give 'overlay' permissions to others and want them to use the Seven theme.  I forgot to mention that this works fine if I am logged in as Admin (user 1) but everyone else gets the custom theme for admin regardless of what I choose.

Comment: 'View administration theme' is a permission. Awkward UX .. :/ if anyone wants to chime in for a quick credited response, ... ahem :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbar - Use the Administrative toolbar is a role permission. Check there if you are having the same problem to make sure it's checked for the role you would like to be able to access the toolbar at the top of the page.